# modifying url with jquery

Tags: jquery, string, url

how would one take part of the current page's url and change just a couple letters of it? Assuming jQuery would be the way to go?

for instance: 
clicking a button counts the number of gets the 19th and 20th character `EN` of

```
www.papercuts.com/EN/boxes/mailingtubes.html
```

and changes it to `DE`

```
www.papercuts.com/DE/boxes/mailingtubes.html
```

Answer (score 2):

and redirects?

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/.com\/.{2}/, '.com/DE');
```

edit: all language support by anstosa

Comment: This will work regardless of what the current language currently is: `window.location = window.location.href.replace(/.com\/.{2}/, '.com/DE');`

Answer (score 0):

```
germanURL = englishURL.replace(/papercuts.com\/EN\//, 'papercuts.com/DE/');
```

Simply use `replace` to replace the `papercuts.com/EN/`.

Comment: this doesnt account for pages not using `www.`

Comment: @Chad I though this would be self explainable, but I'll edit.